# Merge Sort isn't working

Tags: java, eclipse, sorting, arraylist, mergesort

I have written a program in which you can sort an ArrayList using 3 different sort methods: bubble, merge and bogo (or stupid sort). Here's the code:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException;

public class Sorting {

    public static void bubbleSort(ArrayList<Integer> bubble) {
        int temp;
        if (bubble.size() > 1) {
            for (int i = 0; i < bubble.size(); i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < bubble.size() - i - 1; j++) {
                    if (bubble.get(i).compareTo(bubble.get(i + 1)) > 0) {
                        temp = bubble.get(i);
                        bubble.set(i, bubble.get(i + 1));
                        bubble.set(i + 1, temp);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static ArrayList<Integer> mergeSort(ArrayList<Integer> merge) {
        if (merge.size() == 1) {
            return merge;
        } else {
            int halfway = merge.size() / 2;
            ArrayList<Integer> left = new ArrayList<Integer>(halfway);
            ArrayList<Integer> right = new ArrayList<Integer>(merge.size() - halfway);

            for (int i = 0; i < halfway; i++) {
                left.add(merge.get(i));
            }
            for (int i = halfway; i < merge.size(); i++) {
                right.add(merge.get(i));
            }

            left = mergeSort(left);
            right = mergeSort(right);

            ArrayList<Integer> newMerge = new ArrayList<Integer>(merge.size());

            int index1 = 0;
            int index2 = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < merge.size(); i++) {
                if (index1 == left.size()) {
                    merge.set(i, right.get(index2));
                    index2++;
                } else if (index2 == right.size()) {
                    merge.set(i, left.get(index1));
                    index1++;
                } else {
                    if (left.get(index1) <= right.get(index2)) {
                        newMerge.set(i, left.get(index1));
                        index1++;
                    } else if (left.get(index1) >= right.get(index2)) {
                        newMerge.set(i, right.get(index2));
                        index2++;
                    }
                }
            }
            return newMerge;
        }
    }

    public static void bogoSort(ArrayList<Integer> bogo) {
        while (!isOrdered(bogo)) {
            Collections.shuffle(bogo);
        }
    }

    public static boolean isOrdered(ArrayList<Integer> order) {
        for (int i = 0; i < order.size(); i++) {
            if (order.get(i) > order.get(i + 1)) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("random1.txt"));
            ArrayList<Integer> random = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            while (input.hasNextInt()) {
                random.add(input.nextInt());
            }
            input.close();

            System.out.println("Unsorted: " + random);

            long startTime = System.nanoTime();
            bubbleSort(random);
            long endTime = System.nanoTime();
            long duration = ((endTime - startTime) / 1000000);
            System.out.println("Sorted: " + random);
            System.out.println("Bubble sort took: " + duration + " milliseconds to sort.");
            System.out.println();

            long startTime2 = System.nanoTime();
            mergeSort(random);
            long endTime2 = System.nanoTime();
            long duration2 = ((endTime2 - startTime2) / 1000000);
            System.out.println("Sorted: " + random);
            System.out.println("Merge sort took: " + duration2 + " milliseconds to sort.");
            System.out.println();

            long startTime3 = System.nanoTime();
            bogoSort(random);
            long endTime3 = System.nanoTime();
            long duration3 = ((endTime3 - startTime3) / 1000000);
            System.out.println("Sorted: " + random);
            System.out.println("Bogo sort took: " + duration3 + " milliseconds to sort.");
            System.out.println();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("File is not found.");
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }
}
```

When I ran the program, the unsorted ArrayList and the bubble sort method showed up but I received an error with my Merge Sort method, which stated that I have an IndexOutOfBoundsException at lines 38, 57 & 102. I did the algorithm correctly but I don't know why I'm receiving an error. Any reasoning behind this?

Comment: It would help to know which lines are 38, 57 & 102

Comment: 38. left = mergeSort(left); 57. newMerge.set(i, left.get(index1)); 102. mergeSort(random);

Answer (score 1):

## Corrected Code

```
public static ArrayList<Integer> mergeSort(ArrayList<Integer> merge) {
    if (merge.size() == 1) {
        return merge;
    } else {
        int halfway = merge.size() / 2;
        ArrayList<Integer> left = new ArrayList<Integer>(halfway);
        ArrayList<Integer> right = new ArrayList<Integer>(merge.size() - halfway);

        for (int i = 0; i < halfway; i++) {
            left.add(merge.get(i));
        }
        for (int i = halfway; i < merge.size(); i++) {
            right.add(merge.get(i));
        }

        left = mergeSort(left);
        right = mergeSort(right);

        int index1 = 0;
        int index2 = 0;

        // Merge left and right sub-lists into original list
        // See how the newMerge list is no longer needed
        for (int i = 0; i < merge.size(); i++) {
            if (index1 == left.size()) {
                merge.set(i, right.get(index2));
                index2++;
            } else if (index2 == right.size()) {
                merge.set(i, left.get(index1));
                index1++;
            } else {
                if (left.get(index1) <= right.get(index2)) {
                    merge.set(i, left.get(index1)); // We now set the values into merge
                    index1++;
                } else if (left.get(index1) >= right.get(index2)) {
                    merge.set(i, right.get(index2)); // We now set the values into merge
                    index2++;
                }
            }
        }
        return merge; // We now return a reference to merge, not newMerge
    }
}

public static boolean isOrdered(ArrayList<Integer> order) {
    for (int i = 0; i < order.size() - 1; i++) { // order.size() - 1 prevents going out of bounds
        if (order.get(i) > order.get(i + 1)) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

## Elaboration

### Issues with mergeSort()

The issue arises when you begin merging your left and right sub-lists. Note that during the merging process you invoke the `set()` method on both the `newMerge` and `merge` lists. This isn't what you want. Within the "merge"-loop you may attempt to set a value into the `newMerge` list when it is empty, or when `i` is greater than its size. This is the reason for the error you're getting. Since your other sorts seem to sort the original list that was passed in (versus creating a copy, sorting, and returning the copy instead) I can assume your merge sort was intended to do the same. If that's the case, there isn't actually a need for a `newMerge` list at all, since we can just write into the original `merge` list. This change can be seen in the code above.

### Issues with isOrdered()

Minor issue here. You should have terminated your loop when `i == order.size() - 1`, not when `i == order.size()`. Otherwise, when `i == order.size() - 1`, `order.get(i + 1)` will attempt to retrieve an element that does not exist within the list (i.e. out of bounds).

Comment: **Explain** what is going wrong and how to fix it.  Don't repost the OP's entire original code blob, with changes to only one or two lines.   (It might be ok to post just function where changes are required.)

Comment: I was making edits and adding explanations. I specified that when I made my original post (i.e. "Here's the corrected code. I'm adding comments right now...").

Answer (score 1):

To List, you can not add or set element, at specific index, if the index is greater than the size. Check the documentation [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#set-int-E-). You can add null values to your List(newMerge) to fix this or simply add elements to your `newMerge` list. I prefer later. The other `IndexOutOfBoundsException` exceptions are related to this.

Answer (score 0):

> I did the algorithm correctly but I don't know why I'm receiving an error.

Clearly, you haven't done the algorithm correctly, or you wouldn't be getting the exception. ;-)

You are calling:

```
merge.set(i, right.get(index2));
```

and

```
merge.set(i, left.get(index1));
```

which is modifying the original list, not your newly created `newMerge` list which is returned from `mergeSort`.  The caller expects the returned list to have as many elements as it was passed, but (since it is never modified) it actually has zero, which results in the exception in the caller.

Use `newMerge` as the target of your `set` calls, and use `add` instead of trying to set at a particular index.